# Realtek audio issues on OpenBSD 5.2

Tags: audio, openbsd

I am running OpenBSD/amd64 5.2 stable on a new machine, using a gigabyte motherboard with a realtek alc898 audio chipset. When I try to play any audio (sources include `mpd`, `aucat`, and `cat > /dev/audio`), I always end up with the system playing a grinding sound, not quite the same as white noise. I have been able to get the system to play audio under other operating systems, so the hardware is not at fault.

Following the FAQ, `audioctl` and `mixerctl` are not muted and are at reasonable volumes. Following the debugging instructions gave the following:

```
$ cat > /dev/audio < /dev/zero &
[1] 19598
$ audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors}
play.seek=48000
play.samples=3350400
play.errors=0
$ audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors} 
play.seek=48000
play.samples=3696000
play.errors=0
$ audioctl play.{seek,samples,errors} 
play.seek=48000
play.samples=3984000
play.errors=0
$ kill %1
$ fg %1   
cat > /dev/audio < /dev/zero 
Terminated
```

This produces the same grinding noise, even though the FAQ states that this should not produces any noise. `cat /dev/urandom > /dev/audio` produces the same result.

Looking for relevant information in `dmesg`, I found the following:

```
$ dmesg | grep -i audio
azalia0 at pci0 dev 27 function 0 "Intel 7 Series HD Audio" rev 0x04: msi
audio0 at azalia0
azalia0 at pci0 dev 27 function 0 "Intel 7 Series HD Audio" rev 0x04: msi
audio0 at azalia0
$ dmesg | grep -i realtek
azalia0: codecs: Realtek/0x0899, Intel/0x2806, using Realtek/0x0899
azalia0: codecs: Realtek/0x0899, Intel/0x2806, using Realtek/0x0899
```

Is it possible to change the codec to `Intel/0x2806`?
Otherwise is there anything else I can try to resolve the issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

It seems that there have been issues for this chipset on linux, but the solution of an upgraded driver from realtek is not helpful to me.

Comment: Report the bug to the mailing lists. Someone will help you :)

Answer (score 1):

The Realtek alc898 is not supported in the the azalia driver. But from what I can find, it behaves like the alc882, which is supported. Thus it should be very easy to write a patch.